# `didReceiveResponse` called only on first page load, not subsequent ones

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am making an app in which the user can navigate to several pages in `UIWebView`. The links may be broken, and I want to display an error message if the user clicks such a link. This is easy to do via the `didReceiveResponse` function because it has a response object, and we can check the response code, etc.

However, it appears that the `didReceiveResponse` function is called called only when the first page is loaded (and not when the page changes). Which other function can I use in this case which is called every time the user navigates to a different page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the delegate for the WebView and implement this callback method...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Using the request object, you could get the url that the web view wants to load and returning YES in this function will go ahead and load the webpage and returning NO will just simply skips it.

Here is the [AppleDoc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a)

Comment: We do not want the URL, we are interested in the response code. Is there a way to get the respond code via this callback? I guess not, since there is no response object.

Comment: I don't think there is a way with builtin WebView.. what you could do though is, have your own `NSURLConnection` object along with `UIWebView`, and override the above method `webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:` and get the URL from there, call the URL yourself using `NSURLConnection` object, get the response code from NSURLConnection's  delegates and then manually load the WebView with the URL if the response code is what you wanted.

Comment: [Checkout this sample code from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Listings/CustomHTTPProtocol_WebViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013653-CustomHTTPProtocol_WebViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_17) look at `connection:didReceiveResponse:` to see how they are getting status code from response object. Download and try out the example, put debug points... Explore and learn.